# Populate Individual Textbox Values from List Items

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using the following script to populate a textbox after selecting a div.

```
var input = $('input[name="reason"]');
$("ul.instore li").click( function() {
    input.val($(this).attr('value'))
    $("ul.instore li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="instore">
    <li value="1">Option #1</li>
    <li value="2">Option #2</li>
    <li value="3">Option #3</li>
    <li value="4">Option #4</li>
    <li value="5">Option #5</li>
    <li value="6">Option #6</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="reason" />
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zM84Z/

It works like a charm, but now I need to extend it to allow multiple selections.

I've been trying to tweak the script so that clicking on 'Option #1' will populate option 1's textbox (or checkbox, or whatever). Clicking 'Option #2' will populate option 2's textbox, and so on.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out jQuery UI. Here is a link to a demo. http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize

Comment: how do you like to show your new populated textfield? in the current textfield all together?

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to identify the fields

```
<ul class="instore">
    <li value="1">Option #1</li>
    <li value="2">Option #2</li>
    <li value="3">Option #3</li>
    <li value="4">Option #4</li>
    <li value="5">Option #5</li>
    <li value="6">Option #6</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="reason" id="input_1" />
<input type="text" name="reason" id="input_2" />
<input type="text" name="reason" id="input_3" />
<input type="text" name="reason" id="input_4" />
<input type="text" name="reason" id="input_5" />
<input type="text" name="reason" id="input_6" />
```

and jQuery can find them easily using the selector `'#input_' + $(this).val()`

```
$("ul.instore li").click( function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#input_' + val).val(val);
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/zM84Z/3/

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Just one thing... If I want to clear the field when the li is deselected, how might I go about this?